# PixelCompare with right calibration

Tags: autodesk-forge

Use Case: There are several as-built plans as PDF files. The PDF files represent different planning states.

Plan A - as-built plan first floor from 1950 on paper size Letter
Plan B - as-built first floor plan from 1999 on paper size DIN A2
Both plans are scaled to maximum paper width.

Is there a possibility to calibrate the PDF files within the Autodesk Forge Viewer to overlay the files in the correct scaling?

Comment: Would you be able to provide sample documents to test with on our side?

Comment: Thanks. Please suggest how I can share the sample files with you.

Comment: I also provided an answer in the meantime. Does the information there not help?

Answer (score 0):

You have access to the source code of not only the **Viewer** but the **extensions** as well:
https://developer.api.autodesk.com/modelderivative/v2/viewers/7.*/extensions/PixelCompare/PixelCompare.js

Looking in it I did not find a way to specify how the model/sheet should be transformed. However, I found that the **[tool](https://forge.autodesk.com/en/docs/viewer/v7/reference/Viewing/ToolController/)** it's creating is activated **after** the **initialization** is done, which includes changing the **placementTransform** of the secondary sheet in order to adjust the scaling. So I can listen to the **Autodesk.Viewing.TOOL_CHANGE_EVENT** event and adjust the scaling of the sheet:

```
var pcExt = await viewer.loadExtension("Autodesk.Viewing.PixelCompare");

let onToolChange = event => {
    let tr = model2.getPlacementTransform();
    // double scale along X axis
    tr.elements[0] *= 2;
    model2.setPlacementTransform(tr);
    viewer.removeEventListener(Autodesk.Viewing.TOOL_CHANGE_EVENT, onToolChange);
}

viewer.addEventListener(Autodesk.Viewing.TOOL_CHANGE_EVENT, onToolChange);
pcExt.compareTwoModels(model1, model2);
```

This blog post might also be useful:
https://forge.autodesk.com/blog/rotate-sheets-viewer